# How to install a particular version of nvidia-settings?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, bug-reporting

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.Since the latest Nvidia Driver update 396. I have had trouble opening the GUI of Nvidia server X settings so that I could switch between my prime profiles.

So, I would like to know how to install a particular older version of Nvidia (like version 384).

I first did:-

- sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
- sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
  ( Hoping it installs nvidia server X version 384 ( this version used to work correctly for me. ) )

After Installation when I try to know the version by doing `nvidia-settings --version`

It gives output :

> nvidia-settings:  version 396.24  (buildd@lcy01-amd64-016)  Wed May  2 23:28:38
>   UTC 2018
>     The NVIDIA X Server Settings tool.

Also when I try to use `sudo prime-select nvidia`
and then do `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"`

It gives output:

> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>
> Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>
> Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> Serial number of failed request:  35
>
> Current serial number in output stream:  36

I would like to know how to install a previous version of nvidia driver (server X settings) that also install an old version of nvidia-settings or a remedy for the current version of nvidia driver that fixes the GUI and prime profile selection menu.

These issues have also been found by many users on :

[nvidia-settings Unable to load info from any available systems](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032882/linux/nvidia-settings-error-unable-to-load-info-from-any-available-system/)

Sorry for bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken but I thought nvidia-settings was packaged with the driver itself. So to install a different version you'd need a different driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Open `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > Select a newer driver > Apply`
[image]

If that fails, use aptitude instead via: `sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver-418` (or whichever version) and pick a solution that installs the new driver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my doubt was solved earlier just by doing `sudo apt autoremove` and simply installing again, and now I am using `Ubuntu 18.04` .