# Ubuntu 18.04 how to get nvidia-settings version 430 in Wayland

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, wayland, nvidia-settings

Ubuntu recently added updated Nvidia drivers to the 18.04 repository (i.e. not through a ppa). So I upgraded my drivers from version 390 to 430, which is now the recommended version:

```
> ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv00001028sd000006E4bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

However, the package `nvidia-settings` in the repositories appears to be for version 390, and I do not see one for 430. If I install the `nvidia-settings` package from the repositories, attempting to run it outputs

```
ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system
```

whereas if I remove the package, `nvidia-settings` doesn't exist (e.g. it doesn't seem to be packaged with the `nvidia-driver-430` package. Or, if it is, I cannot find it).

I think the nvidia driver is running correctly, as `nvidia-smi` outputs

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2004MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Is there a way to install a specific version of `nvidia-settings` to match my driver version?**

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1046947/569198) is very similar, but the accepted and only answer says that `nvidia-settings` should be packaged with the driver, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

Let me know if any additional information would be helpful!

EDIT: I just tried switching my display server from Wayland to Xorg, and upon logging back in under Xorg, suddenly `nvidia-settings` works! This is still slightly confusing, as it still indicates that it is nvidia-settings version 390.

Regardless, I would ideally like to be able to stay on Wayland. Is there a way to get `nvidia-settings` to work under Wayland?

Comment: Have You disabled nouveau driver? What is the output of `sudo lshw -C display | grep -i driver` ?  You can disable nouveau during boot (or in grub config) by adding line `nouveau.blacklist=1`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz, yes nouveau is disabled. The output is `configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0, configuration: driver=i915 latency=0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No version of nvidia-settings has ever been able to run in a wayland session.

Whether this is resolved down the road is unclear though certainly won't be in the immediate future as Ubuntu's switch to wayland will not happen till after 20.04 and even then nvidia-settings would be a low priority.

A newer verion of nvidia-settings for 18.04 is only available via a ppa.

Comment: When or what is 20.04?

Comment: The next LTS Ubuntu release..

Comment: does the driver itself work with wayland? (the settings window is not important to me since all defaults are good and since most options can be changed from the ubuntu settings menu anyways)

Comment: That's not exactly clear to me. On an optimus laptop I have  when logging into a wayland session it falls back automatically to Intel. On a nvidia only laptop I have when logging into a wayalnd session I get llvmpipe. So for me no.. Whether some desktop machine can use nvidia in wayland I don't have the hardware to see. As far as Ubuntu,  as of 19.10 they are blacklisting wayland if nvidia is detected..   So from Ubuntu side it doesn't work or even if possible works poorly.