# ubuntu 19.04 wayland on Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, wayland

Everywhere I google every article and stack question and forum post seems to imply that wayland ships with ubuntu 19.04 ready to be used.

The implication seems to be that you can log, out click on the cog/gear dropdown and select "Ubuntu" instead of "Ubuntu on X.org" and this will log you in to wayland.

Here's what really happens : you log out ... there is no cog/gear icon, or anywhere else you can click.

After installing `gnome-session-wayland` and several reboots later, the login screen finally has a cog icon with two options : "Gnome on X.org" and "Ubuntu" selecting "Ubuntu" (was my default session) and typing `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` into the terminal gives me "x11". on "Gnome on X.org", the result is obviously the same.

Maybe this is pertinent : I'm on nvidia and have installed the nvidia drivers from `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

What is a step-by-step guide to landing on a wayland desktop from a vanilla ubuntu 19.04 install on Nvidia?

Update : I found this : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Wayland_sessions

I tried adding :

```
if [[ -z $DISPLAY && $(tty) == /dev/tty1 && $XDG_SESSION_TYPE == tty ]]; then
  XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland exec dbus-run-session gnome-session
fi
```

to my `.profile` and logged out and back in, this did nothing.

Update 2 :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-418/+bug/1823516

it seems as if there is a problem with current nvidia driver. this would not explain the missing cog option though.

there has been no communiqué that I know of from Canonical about hiding this option untill the issue is resolved and I imagine it wouldn't hide itself.

Comment: When I installed 19.04 on my hardware, the Wayland option was available at first boot, and it works wonderfully. Wayland DOES work for lots of folks, your hardware happens to be a corner-case.

Comment: @user535733 thank you, interesting, however Nvidia seems to not be a preventing factor altogether : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166496/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-get-nvidia-settings-version-430-in-wayland